# Which part of WifiInfo can be used to distinguish every unique access point in a big WLAN?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Which part of `WifiInfo` can be used to distinguish every unique access point in a big WLAN?
`BSSID` or `MAC address`?

Comment: You could use any, i, personally, would use BSSID. Essentially for access points (Infrastructure mode) BSSID is MAC address of that access point (wireless side MAC).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what's the getMacAddress() return?

Comment: I think it should return MAC address of remote wireless adapter. For example, BSSID is not required to be equal to MAC address, it just required to be unique within all accessible WiFi adapters in range. If you use AdHoc mode, BSSID usually set to random value instead of adapter's MAC address. It is also possible to use single WiFi adapter to maintain several different networks, so in that case MAC adress couldn't be used for BSSID, since it is used to separate packets in one network from packets in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSSID of access point is essential to every device.

You should get a WifiManager instance and then call

```
wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID()
```

to retrieve the BSSID as a string, it is just the MAC address of your AP, format like 0C:DE:AD:1F:00:32

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what's the getMacAddress() return?

Comment: getMacAddress() will return your WLAN interface's (wifi adapter device on your phone) mac address.